Low frame-rate w/events in R3F + DREI views
I'm having an issue with basic react-three-fiber events, specifically in the context of Drei Views (although that may or may not be related, and I'm hoping I'm just missing a simple implementation step).
Full details at end.
The specific problem is this: if I add any event function to my model, I immediately get a hit in frame rate. When I say "any", I mean this works fine:
    return (
        <points ref={ref}>
            <bufferGeometry
                width={1}
                height={1}
                widthSegments={1}
                heightSegments={1}
            >
                {/* bufferAttribues */}
            </bufferGeometry>
            <shaderMaterial
                // material args
            />
        </points>
     )

but if I change it to <points ref={ref} onClick={() => {}}> then just scrolling (i.e., not clicking) drops the frame rate from 60 to somewhere between 30 and 50. Of course, I want to actually do something, not just have the event be a noop — I got here from my attempts to debug, because my original code was
    const shaderRef = useRef();

    const pointerMoveHandler = ((e) => {
        shaderRef.current.uniforms.uMouse.value = e.point;
    })

    return (
        <points ref={ref} onPointerMove={pointerMoveHandler}>
            <bufferGeometry
                width={1}
                height={1}
                widthSegments={1}
                heightSegments={1}
            >
                {/* bufferAttribues */}
            </bufferGeometry>
            <shaderMaterial
                ref={shaderRef}
                uniforms={{
                        uMouse: { value: new Vector3(0, 0, 0) },
                        // other uniforms
                    }}
                // other material args
            />
        </points>
     )

wherein if I moved the mouse over the model, the frame rate drops to single digits! The crazy thing is, if I enable OrbitControls, I can zoom in and out, and spin things around 'til my hearts' content, and it smoothly runs along at 60 FPS the whole time.
What I've tried so far:

making sure OrbitControls are turned off, in case there was some competition for who was capturing events.
confirming that the model isn't re-rendering a bunch:


<points ref={ref}>
    {console.log('points rendered')}

(it doesn't; it only renders once)


wrapping the whole thing in a bounding volume hierarchy


    return (
      <Bvh>
          <points ref={ref} onPointerMove={pointerMoveHandler}>
          // ...
          </points>
      </Bvh>
    )



Force the latest version of BVH (Drei is currently one version back and there's a build warning about deprecation, plus there appear to be some improvements, so ... why not?)


// package.json
"overrides": {
  "@react-three/drei": {
    "three-mesh-bvh": "~0.8.2"
  }
}



Tried to stop propagation


const pointerMoveHandler = ((e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    shaderRef.current.uniforms.uMouse.value = e.point;
})



Randomly hoped that useCallback would do something ¯\(ツ)/¯


const pointerMoveHandler = useCallback(((e) => {
    shaderRef.current.uniforms.uMouse.value = e.point;
}), [props])


What am I doing wrong here?
Based on all of the above attempts, I'm now down to assuming I'm doing something wrong specifically with respect to how Drei views are handling event propagation. Here's a simplified version of the whole stack (condensed to eliminate use client directives and dynamic imports for making this work in NextJS, etc...):
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <main>
        <div ref={localRef} />
        <r3f.In>
          <View track={localRef}> // Drei view
            <Points /> // the problematic code from above
            <PerspectiveCamera />
            {orbit && <OrbitControls />}
            <Stats />
          </View>
        </r3f.In>
      </main>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        touchAction={'auto'}
      >
        <Canvas
          pointerEvents={'none'}
          eventSource={ref}
          eventPrefix={'client'}
        >
          <r3f.Out />
          <Preload all />
        </Canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Not strictly-speaking minimal, but I put a codesandbox up.
P.S., my personal plan while I hope and wait for an answer here is to go dig into the source code for OrbitControls and see if I can find something there.

From briefly looking at what you are trying to achiever, useFrame seems a place you wanna do that

Meaning I want to put the event handler function inside of the useFrame callback?

You don’t want event handler in this case, you want to write mouse position to uniform, during frame, the event may occur more then once per frame, if you want to keep that way you likely need to throttle.

And onClick handler for points is slow because likely that an instanced draw and you raycast against each point individually, you can test that by reducing amount of points

It seems @antokhio's comment was correct, and there's some problem with using R3F's effects in a point geometry. For my particular case, I was able to fix it by adding an invisible simple plane:
return (
    <>
    // original model (<points>)
    <mesh ref={testRef} onPointerDown={mouseDown} onPointerUp={mouseUp} onWheel={wheel}>
        <planeGeometry args={[1000, 1000]} />
        <meshBasicMaterial transparent opacity={0.0} depthWrite={false} />
    </mesh>
    </>
)

Then the event callbacks on the mesh worked smoothly. I also moved the specific functionality of updating the projected mouse position inside of useFrame so as not to worry about the "mouse moving faster than frame rate" issue and creating gratuitous re-renders. I just cast a ray to the new invisible mesh (testRef):
    useFrame((state, delta, xrFrame) => {
        const { raycaster } = state;
        const hovered = raycaster.intersectObjects([testRef.current]);

        if (hovered.length) {
            shaderRef.current.uniforms.uMouse.value.x = hovered[0].point.x;
            shaderRef.current.uniforms.uMouse.value.y = hovered[0].point.y;
        }
    })

My case was simple, as I just needed the projected mouse position if the mouse was anywhere near my object. But if you needed more specificity, you might need to draw a better box around your original mesh, rather than just using a simple plane.
